# Indexing on low-cardinality field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have a table with 1M rows and a boolean field where 80% of the values are `true` and 20% are `false`. If I am filtering on this field frequently, would it be of use adding in an index?

My thought would be yes, in that a database could limit the records down to ~ 20% of a full table scan (and using the `NOT IN <ids>` for the case where there are 80% of the records). Is this an accurate assessment of how an index would be used/created in the above case? Is an index able to traverse the "NOT case" as in the above, or it can only traveling along positively-matching records?

Comment: Did it really help you ? How you tested.Can you provide your observation and feedback, so that it help other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not useful to add a standard index.  An index helps a query by reducing the number of pages that are read.  In general, there are more than five records on a page, so you would expect every page to have a "true" value.

You could use a *clustered* index, with the boolean column as the first value in the index.  This would then limit the number of pages to about 20% of the pages.  Clustered indexes do incur overhead on `insert` and `update` (on the clustered columns).  Whether it is worth incurring that overhead depends on your overall application.

Comment: could you please show an example of how a possible clustered index would be created?

Comment: @TagC198 . . . Hint:  `create clustered index . . . `.